# How to econometrically identify perfect complements in production?

Tags: mathematical-economics, production-function, applied-econometrics

The production

$$f(x_i,...,x_n)=\min\{x_i,...,x_n\}$$

is pretty straight forward and usually with smaller size data sets and can usually be picked up on rather quickly in an intuitive sense.

However if one has a very large set of data with a firm that produces $n$ products, how does one go about analyzing the production process and say that such a relationship exists in production of a given good?

Comment: Relevant:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313272/identifying-a-min-x-1-x-2-in-a-regression