# Does multicolinearity of variables imply complementary inputs?

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics

I've been thinking about how to answer this question [How to econometrically identify perfect complements in production?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/19005/how-to-econometrically-identify-perfect-complements-in-production) and may think that multicollinearity has something to do with identifying such a process.

If I have a regression such that:

$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\mu$$

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are correlated with each other.

does that imply that some function of the nature $\min\{x_1,x_2\}$ is present in the determination of $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Leontief production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leontief_production_function) does imply perfect multicollinearity between the inputs, since there is no substitutability between them. Thus, if a firm's production technology features non-substitutability between inputs, one would observe the firm choosing inputs in fixed proportions.

However, (perfect) multicollinearity does not necessarily imply non-substitutability. For instance, the Cobb-Douglas production technology of the form $y=x_1^{0.5}x_2^{0.5}$ is also consistent with a firm choosing inputs in fixed proportions. So the answer to your question is no (from a theoretical perspective).

Comment: edited my question. Thanks for the definition

Comment: But in a case of fundamentally different $x_1$ and $x_2$ where they are not  a linear combination of one another is this contradiction still true